# Update previous rows based on the value of next row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to update the NULL rows by 'FULL' value if there's a 'FULL' value on the succeeding rows considering they are in the same group (by min) and order (by month_no and year).

Here's the sample table

```
min   month_no   year  remarks
001     1       2019   FULL
001     2       2019   NULL
001     3       2019   FULL
002     1       2019   NULL
002     2       2019   NULL
002     3       2019   FULL
003     1       2019   NULL
003     2       2019   FULL
003     3       2019   NULL
```

I have tried the code below but it just copies the next row value, without considering the grouping.

```
select 
         min
        ,month_no
        ,year
        ,remarks
        LEAD(remarks) OVER (ORDER BY min, month_no, year) NextValue
from [table]
order by month_no, year
```

Here's my expected output:

```
    min   month_no  year remarks  newremarks
    001     1       2019   FULL     FULL
    001     2       2019   NULL     FULL
    001     3       2019   FULL     FULL
    002     1       2019   NULL     FULL
    002     2       2019   NULL     FULL
    002     3       2019   FULL     FULL
    003     1       2019   NULL     FULL
    003     2       2019   FULL     FULL
    003     3       2019   NULL     NULL
```

The NULLs for the min 001 and 002 are 'FULL' in the newremarks column because there's a value with 'FULL' in the succeeding rows.

Comment: your examples all have the same year but if they didn't, wouldn't `year,month_nr` be a more natural ordering than `month_no,year`?

Comment: NewRemarks of Row "002     1       2019", will be NULL or FULL. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this can be achieved with simple window functions with PARTITION and ORDER BY and an aggregate like MIN or MAX. You can't use LEAD because you are looking at all the succeeding rows in a group, not just the one immediately succeeding:

> ```
> select mi,month_no,year,remarks
>      , newremarks =
>        max(remarks) over (partition by mi order by month_no desc ,year desc)
> from foo
> order by mi,month_no,year;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> mi  | month_no | year | remarks | newremarks
> :-- | -------: | ---: | :------ | :---------
> 001 |        1 | 2019 | FULL    | FULL      
> 001 |        2 | 2019 | null    | FULL      
> 001 |        3 | 2019 | FULL    | FULL      
> 002 |        1 | 2019 | null    | FULL      
> 002 |        2 | 2019 | null    | FULL      
> 002 |        3 | 2019 | FULL    | FULL      
> 003 |        1 | 2019 | null    | FULL      
> 003 |        2 | 2019 | FULL    | FULL      
> 003 |        3 | 2019 | null    | null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=559599553a78abbfb9df3a4b66782741&hide=3)*

Comment: `year` should be before `mon` in the `order by`.

Comment: That makes sense [to me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55722960/update-previous-rows-based-on-the-value-of-next-row/55723110?noredirect=1#comment98126011_55722960), but it wouldn't be consistent with the OPs post.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
;WITH CTE([min], month_no, [year], remarks)
AS
( 
SELECT 001, 1, 2019, 'FULL'     UNION ALL
SELECT 001, 2, 2019, NULL       UNION ALL
SELECT 001, 3, 2019, 'FULL'     UNION ALL
SELECT 002, 1, 2019, NULL       UNION ALL
SELECT 002, 2, 2019, NULL       UNION ALL
SELECT 002, 3, 2019, 'FULL'     UNION ALL
SELECT 003, 1, 2019, NULL       UNION ALL
SELECT 003, 2, 2019, 'FULL' UNION ALL
SELECT 003, 3, 2019, NULL
)
SELECT  [min], 
        month_no, 
        [year],
         LEAD(NewRemarks,1)OVER(ORDER BY [MIn]) AS NewRemarks 
FROM
(
SELECT  [min], 
        month_no,
        [year],
        Remarks,
        CASE WHEN Remarks IS NOT NULL THEN Remarks 
        ELSE
           (SELECT Top 1 Remarks 
            FROM CTe i
            WHERE  i.[year] = o.[year]              
            )END AS NewRemarks 
FROM CTE o
)dt
```

Result

```
min month_no    year    NewRemarks
----------------------------------
1       2       2019      FULL
1       3       2019      FULL
1       1       2019      FULL
2       1       2019      FULL
2       2       2019      FULL
2       3       2019      FULL
3       2       2019      FULL
3       3       2019      FULL
3       1       2019      NULL
```